# Boot DOS from USB to copy data from HDD to external HDD

Tags: crash, file-recovery

My Windows machine's HDD won't boot anymore.  Windows repair/recovery is also failing.  I'm hoping there is a way I can achieve the following:

Boot DOS (or something else?) from a USB Key, such that I can copy files from the existing failing HDD to an external USB HDD?

Please help.

Comment: DOS isn't supported on modern computers, their UEFI BIOS is not compatible with it, the `Windows Recovery Console` is very useful in a case like this.  You don't indicate what prevents you from booting and/or the failure within the Windows Repair process.

Comment: [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) will boot from a CD or pendrive. [HBCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) is also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like Ubuntu (you can [install to a USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)) and you'll be fine. Just about any Linux distro (including a Live CD, for example) can get your files.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned booting to DOS is probably not your best option.  I would create a Linux USB drive or DVD and boot to that.  Make sure you "live boot" and don't actually install Linux on your broken computer.  Live booting won't effect your existing file system, i.e. all your files will be in tact.

Once you have booted to Linux, you can open "explorer" although it will be called something else depending on the Linux you picked.  I would recommend Ubuntu.  From there, you will be able to copy all your files off, attempt a recovery, fix disk errors etc.

I found a great tutorial on Lifehacker that will walk you through step by step if you're not very comfortable in Linux.

http://lifehacker.com/192982/geek-to-live--rescue-files-with-a-boot-cd